# Spring Data JPA Distinct Returning Duplicate Values

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring boot application I have a query which should return a distinct List of Focus' (works perfectly in MySQL)

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Focus F " +
            "JOIN FrameworkFoci FF on FF.focusID = F.focusID " +
            "JOIN FocusGroups FG on FF.frameworkID = FG.frameworkID " +
            "JOIN GroupMembers GM on FG.groupID = GM.groupID " +
            "JOIN Users U on GM.userID = U.userID " +
            "WHERE U.userID = :userID", nativeQuery = true)
List<Focus> findByUserID(@Param("userID") Long userID);
```

However this does not return distinct values, duplicates are contained in the resulting list. Another issue is that I can't return a whole entity using `@Query` annotation - changing my query to `SELECT DISTINCT(F) FROM Focus F` gives the error `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'F' in 'field list'`.

Furthermore, I tried changing adjusting the query to the following

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM FrameworkFoci FF " +
        "JOIN FocusGroups FG on FF.frameworkID = FG.frameworkID " +
        "JOIN GroupMembers GM on FG.groupID = GM.groupID " +
        "JOIN Users U on GM.userID = U.userID " +
        "WHERE U.userID = :userID", nativeQuery = true)
```

however this produced the error `java.sql.SQLException: Column 'focusCategory' not found.`

Why is the query not returning distinct values? And why can't I return a whole entity nor use the second query?

Focus Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Focus {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long focusID;

@Column(name = "focusCategory")
private String focusCategory;

private String focusName;

private String focusExplanation;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "focus")
private Set<Rating> ratings;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "FrameworkFoci",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "focusID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "frameworkID"))
private Set<Framework> frameworks;

//image

protected Focus(){}

public Focus(String focusName, String focusCategory, String focusExplanation) {
    this.focusCategory = focusCategory;
    this.focusName = focusName;
    this.focusExplanation = focusExplanation;
}

public Focus(String focusCategory, String focusName, String focusExplanation, Set<Rating> ratings){
    this.focusCategory = focusCategory;
    this.focusName = focusName;
    this.focusExplanation = focusExplanation;
    this.ratings = ratings;
}

public Long getFocusId() {
    return focusID;
}

public void setFocusId(Long focusID) {
    this.focusID = focusID;
}

public String getFocusCategory() {
    return focusCategory;
}

public void setFocusCategory(String focusCategory) {
    this.focusCategory = focusCategory;
}
```

EDIT:

I've switched from SQL to JPQL with the following query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT focus FROM Focus focus " +
                "WHERE focus.frameworks.groups.groupMembers.user.userID =:userID ")
```

I now get an error `org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [focus0_.focusID.frameworks] with element property reference [groups]`

Framework entity:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "frameworkID")
public class Framework {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long frameworkID;

    private String frameworkName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "FrameworkFoci",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "frameworkID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "focusID"))
    private Set<Focus> frameworkFoci = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "framework", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Group> groups;

    public Framework(){}
```

Comment: To select distinct entities using jpql you have to use `select distinct f from Focus f` instead of `select distinct * from Focus f` and `select DISTINCT(f) from Focus f`

Comment: @alexvaluiskyi They are using SQL not JPQL, which I assume is part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query solves the issue

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT focus FROM Focus focus " +
                "JOIN focus.frameworks frameworks " +
                "JOIN frameworks.groups groups " +
                "JOIN groups.groupMembers groupMembers "+
                "WHERE groupMembers.userID =:userID ")     
    List<Focus> findByUserID(@Param("userID") Long userID);
```

Frameworks and GroupMembers are collections and hence needed to be joined, otherwise `illegal attempt to dereference collection [focus0_.focusID.frameworks] with element property reference [groups]` was produced

Answer (score 0):

you should write your query like this:
'
SELECT DISTINCT f FROM Focus F '

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from you using SQL by specifying `nativeQuery = true`. SQL doesn't know about entities, just tables.

Since you presumably have many `FrameworkFoci` rows (and rows in all the other tables) for each `Focus` row, each `Focus` row gets repeated for each matching row in `FrameworkFoci`. This kind of duplicates the `Focus` row but the resulting rows are still distinct, because they differ in the columns from the other tables.

And then each row gets turned into a `Focus` entity, probably with a single element in the `framework` set.

So therefore query doesn't so much return duplicate results as results split into multiple entities.

Fortunately the solution should be fairly simple: Use JPQL which should be perfectly possible, since you're using only simple joins.

The following should give you a start:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Focus F " +
    "WHERE F.framework.groupMembers.user.id=:userID")
List<Focus> findByUserID(@Param("userID") Long userID);
```

Comment: This makes sense to me for one-to-one mappings, but how would this work when both frameworks and groupMembers are many-to-many?

Comment: This is for one-to-many and many-to-many cases. For one-to-one or many-to-one there isn't a problem because one source row results in 0-1 result row.

Comment: I see, trying this way I get 'illegal attempt to dereference collection [focus0_.focusID.frameworks] with element property reference [groups]', a Framework holds a List of Groups - I imagine I have to do WHERE focus.frameworks.groups.groupMembers.user.userID =:userID  however this is not working